# what are ICMP type and code are used for the ICMP echo request

Tags: icmp

I would like to know what are the Internet Control Message Protocol type and Internet Control Message Protocol code are used for the Internet Control Message Protocol echo request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol.

Echo Reply   Type:0 Code:0
 Echo Request Type:8 Code:0